# ASP.NET Core : How to add input programmatically and pass data to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to add a Service which contains 'Title and description' and each service contains a list of fields.

Service class

```
public class Services : BaseEntity
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "هذا الحقل مطلوب")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceFields> ServiceFields { get; set; }
}
```

`ServiceFields` class

```
public class ServiceFields : BaseEntity
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "هذا الحقل مطلوب")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

And pass the title, description and all the fields to the controller

Comment: Do you mean [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) ? What's your controller looks like? Could you share your code of controller  and view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create Validator. Please check "Fleunt Validation".
It is the right way to validate request object